# Partial View not being loaded by Javascript when table is clicked

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, view, partial-views

I have a table that, when clicked, should load up the Partial View. I put a breakpoint in the Controller's ActionResult RetrieveItemPrice(), it successfully goes to the return statement but it's not displaying the PartialView in my View.

Controller (ItemController)

```
public ActionResult RetrieveItemPrice()
{
    return PartialView("~/Views/Item/_ViewItemPrice");
}
```

View (Create)

```
...
<div class="col-sm-8" style="border: 0px solid green; padding:10px;">
    <div id="pvItemPrice" class="" style="border: 0px solid green; ">
    </div>
</div>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dbTable").click(function (e) {
            debugger;
            $("#pvItemPrice").load('/Item/RetrieveItemPrice');
        });
    });
</script>
```

PartialView (_ViewItemPrice)

```
@model CDS.Models.ItemViewModel
@using PagedList.Mvc;

<div>
    <table id="dbTable2" class="table table-hover" aria-busy="false">
        <thead>
            <tr class="inner-table-head">
                <th class="hidden">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.itemId)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Item", "Create", new { currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Price", "Create", new { currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="dbBody2">
            @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td class="hidden">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.itemid)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.itemdesc)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.itemprice)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You not passing a model to the partial view so the code in it would throw a `NullReferenceException` - you cannoy access the `Items` property of `null` (I suspect your getting a `500(Internal Server Error)` in the browser)

Comment: Oh! I can understand you now! I have a LINQ in my `JsonResult Create` that returns the view in Create. But I don't have one in `ActionResult RetrieveItemPrice`. Am I right? Btw, I'm not getting `500(Internal Server Error)`

Comment: But I think at least it should display my header table. I'm gonna try to experiment first

Comment: Right now, I tried simplifying the PartialView to `<div>Hello</div>` only, and removed the `@model` code at the top. When I click the table from my Create View it's still not displaying the PartialView that will output the Hello. Is there anything I missed?

Comment: You would have got a error in the browser console because the partial view throws an exception. If you have replaced all the code in the view with just `<div>Hello</div>` then your code will work fine (although I would use `return PartialView("_ViewItemPrice");`)

Answer (score 0):

Where is the model being passed into the view (CDS.Models.ItemViewModel)?

```
return PartialView("~/Views/Item/_ViewItemPrice");
```

Also, what does network tools show as a response? A 200 or 500 response code?

Comment: Are you asking questions in an answer? i think you should show to OP that *how to pass model with partial view*

Comment: I can see now that I don't have a LINQ in my `ActionResult RetrieveItemPrice()`. Thanks! @Div 's right though. And also, I think it should at least display the table header. I don't use any model for that. I'll get back to you guys

Comment: Tried to simplify my PartialView to pinpoint the problem, now it only has <div>Hello</div> code. But it still doesn't show up when I click the table in `Create`

Comment: If any part of the view creation fails then it does not return what was compiled in the view. Do you still have any references in the view to models etc?